# How does servlet container process this http request?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a `Dynamic Web Project` using Eclipse for the first time to work with servlet and jsp.

Below is the servlet code,

```
package com.example.tutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");

        out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }

}
```

and corresponding web.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ServletsJSPExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ServletExample</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.tutorial.ServletExample</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletexample</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have also written `index.jsp` which has below form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="servletexample" method="post" >
       <table border="0">
         <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="lastname"  /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my first case, Within eclipse, If I select `Run As -> Run On Server`, browser within eclipse shows presentation code of `index.jsp`  with URI: `http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/`

I later add below line of code in servlet,

```
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

as shown below,

```
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");

        out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    }

}
```

In second case, Within eclipse, If I select `Run As -> Run On Server`, browser within eclipse shows presentation code of `index.jsp`  with URI: `http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/servletexample`

So,

Wrt these two cases, How is this URI getting changed? 
How control is flowing from servlet container to my application `ServletsJSPExample` before and after adding this line of code `this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Please help me understand this!!!

*Note: `ServletsJSPExample` is "dynamic web project" name in eclipse*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget about Eclipse and how you launch your program within it. This is about Servlets, their url-mappings, and the urls you hit.

In your first sample, you hit

```
http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/
```

Assuming `ServletsJSPExample` is your context root, you're reaching the root of your app. Since you have a `welcome-file` registered (which is a JSP)

```
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

the Servlet container will serve it directly.

In the second case, you send your request to

```
http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/servletexample
```

which has a path of `/servletexample`. You have your `ServletExample` servlet mapped to

```
<url-pattern>/servletexample</url-pattern>
```

so the Servlet container chooses this `ServletExample` servlet to handle the request. Handling the request means invoking its `service` method, which goes on to invoke

```
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

With the call to [`getRequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) the container

> Returns a `RequestDispatcher` object that acts as a wrapper for the resource located at the given path.

The resource located at the given path, in this case, is a JSP (another `Servlet`). With your call to `forward`, you are, down the line, invoking `service` on the JSP servlet. That renders the content of your JSP and sends it as the response body.

Comment: I understand your first line of answer. When you say: `you send your request to`, I did not send explicitly, instead I say `Run On Server` So, why servlet container is picking servlet `http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/servletexample` in second case but not `index.jsp` ,

Comment: @overexchange I don't know how Eclipse chooses its urls. And it's not important. If you change the url and send your request to `http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/`, the JSP will be served directly just like your first case. Your servlet won't be involved at all.

Comment: Can you please add more information about, what exactly is this `this.getServletContext()`? Why do we use it?

Comment: @overexchange [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext%28%29) the javadoc. It retrieves the `ServletContext`, which is a collection of attributes and configurations that apply to the entirety of your web application.

Comment: `Gets the servlet context to which this ServletRequest was last dispatched.` What does this mean? What is the meaning of `ServletContext` ?

Comment: @overexchange Follow the javadoc. There's a link to the `ServletContext`, _which is a collection of attributes and configurations that apply to the entirety of your web application_

Comment: For the above code to run correctly, requestdispatch should be called when request.getParameter("first name and last name") is null.when both params are null, what is the necessity to again forward these two parameters to service method of JSP servlet by saying forward(request, response)? What is wrong if I say "forward(null, null)"?

Answer (score 1):

The URI won't change. What changes is the content of the response.

When using this:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

It means you will manually write the content of the response of this request. Everything you write in `out` will be part of the response. This is why,if you only write this:

```
out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
```

The only text in the response is this text, no HTML at all. When calling `http://localhost:8081/ServletsJSPExample/servletexample` the browser will display this plain text, and that's all.

When using this:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

It means that the content of `index.jsp` will be used as part of the response. The content of `index.jsp` will be parsed by using the attributes in `HttpServletRequest request` (thus *replacing* the content of Expression Language, those expressions enclosed in `${}`).

Comment: When you write servlets and jsp stuff, One reconmends to introduce servlets in such a way that one should not access jsp pages in URL. Why is this recommended?

Comment: Because the Servlet will act as controller and it's its responsibility to execute the (reusable) Java code and call the view (JSP) for the response. The JSP is not the proper place to write Java code (via scriptlets), but instead it should be used to place view-related logic.

Comment: Do you mean  url-mapping of controller should be  part of URLgiven in the browser? But not url mapping of view(which is jsp here)

Comment: I never mentioned url mapping in the comment. That's not its meaning.